# How can i fix the background according to the web page in css?

Tags: html, css

I set radius background with fix width and height but when i do zoom out at that time it's reflect for content only not reflecting on background. How can i fix that?

This is my current page:-
[image]

When i zoom out web page background remaining same it doesn't change

[image]

Here is my css code:-

```
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
    width:100%;
    height:40vw;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80%;
    background-color:  #f0f5f5; 
 }
```

Here is my html code :-

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Join Pragra!</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    <button class="btn">Contact us!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="/assets/images/faq-banner.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is happening because you set its width to 100%, regardless if you zoom it out, it will still occupy the whole width of its parent element. The same goes for it's height, you set it to 40vw (viewport width). You have to either set a fixed value for its own width and height or its parent element's.

Comment: You could implement a solution in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're setting the height to 40vh (viewport height), so no matter you zoom it or wide it, it's still have 40vh (40% of the height of your browser window).
So the solution is very simple : Just set the value to fixed number, for example :

```
.bg {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Ya it's working now... Thank u so much... Do you have any idea for width?

Comment: So you want the width to resize when you resize the window?

Comment: I don't get it, you've set the width to 100%, that mean it will always be 100% with your window's width. So it should auto resize now, what is the problem?

Comment: when i zoom out it is showing full width according the webpage.... Did u get my point?

Comment: ahh.. I think you should put your .bg div into another div (like a container), and then you set the container div with a fixed number. And then set the .bg width:100%;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217510/discussion-between-devanshi-and-phuc-h).